# On Windows, C#, Does Socket.BeginReceive() take a background thread before or after the data arrives?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

If it take a background thread before the data arrives, and when many connections waiting for data, there will be too many threads exist, causing performance degradation. is there an approach to wait for data without taking a thread?

Comment: [There is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Answer (score 2):

`Socket.BeginReceive()`, and other asynchronous I/O methods in .NET, make use of the IOCP thread pool. The short version is that this is a *very* efficient way to manage I/O. There is practically no cost to wait for the I/O to complete, and even once it completes, your completion callback is called from a thread pool thread, tying up that thread only for as long as it takes for your callback to complete.

"IOCP" stands for "IO Completion Ports", a feature in the native Windows API. The basic idea is that you can have a single thread, or some small collection of threads, all ready to service the completion of a large number of I/O operations. This allows I/O operations to scale well into the hundreds of thousands, if not millions, of concurrent operations, while still only requiring a relatively small number of threads to deal with them all.

So, go right ahead use those asynchronous I/O APIs. They are the *best* way to write scalable I/O code.

*(Aside: the `Socket` class in particular has a number of async options. Ironically, the methods ending in `...Async` do not comply with the new(er) `async`/`await` paradigm in C#, but they are in fact the most scalable way to do I/O with a `Socket`, because not only do they use the IOCP thread pool, they also allow you to reuse your I/O state objects, so you can have a pool of those and minimize GC load.)*

Comment: I don't claim to have any knowledge of IO Completion Ports past what you've posted above, but I'm sure I remember reading somewhere that the completion callback is executed on the same thread that many other IO tasks could be monitored on, hence blocking their completion.  Does this sound correct or am I mistaken?  I always thought it was best to push the result of `EndReceive` onto a queue and handle it in the thread-pool.

Comment: @Luke: That's why it's a thread _pool_, and not just one thread. Yes, like any thread pool thread, you should finish your operation as quickly as possible, so the thread can be returned to the pool. And done wrong, you certainly could wind up blocking all of the other I/O operations. This is a risk with any thread pool implementation. The solution is "don't do that". :) I.e. don't exhaust the pool of threads by keeping them busy all the time. This does not typically require moving one thread pool operation onto a different thread pool though.

Comment: So the callbacks are executed on threads in the default .NET thread pool?

Comment: @Luke: _"the callbacks are executed on threads in the default .NET thread pool"_ -- sort of. The .NET `ThreadPool` class actually manages two thread pools. The one you get with `QueueUserWorkItem()` is different from the IOCP thread pool used with I/O operations. But both are managed by that class.

Comment: Right, makes sense, that must be what I was thinking of and also explains the performance increase from pushing work from the completion callback with `QueueUserWorkItem`.  Thanks for your explanation.