# BeginSend not returning immediately

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

Client Code::

```
IDGSocketClient client = new IDGSocketClient();
client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
client.Send("dadsa" );
```

---

IDGSocketClient Class

```
public void Connect(string ipAddress, int port)
{
    clientSocket.Connect(ipAddress, port);
}

public void Send(string data, int i)
{
    Console.Write("send called");
    Socket socket = clientSocket.Client;
    byte[] a =  { 1, 2 };
    socket.BeginSend(a, 0,1, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
    Console.Write("Send Returned");
}
public void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    while (true) ;
}
```

Server :

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8888);
serverSocket = new TcpListener(ipEndPoint);
serverSocket.Start();
TcpClient client = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
```

---

Now I would expect BeginSend to return immediately or at least after some time, but it's not the case here.

Output

```
send called
```

whereas shouldn't the output be

```
send calledSend Returned
```

To rephrase : 
BeginSend is a method which according to documentation should call the callback function in a new thread, the thread in which it was called wouldn't be blocked(unless done manually). 
In my case, even though the callback has an infinite loop , that should execute in a different thread, and the thread which called beginSend should execute the next Console.Write Statement in my opinion.

Comment: Why do you have an infinite loop in your callback?

Comment: Actually I am waiting for some purpose(in actual program it's not an infinite loop), and getting the error, to replicate for demo purposes I am using infinite loop in callback. In any case that shouldn't affect the question, right?

Comment: You are connecting to the loop back address, mostly your callback is returning before `Console.Write("Send Returned")` is executed and its an infinite loop thus hung, make it a valid call back, would be easy to debug

Comment: @MrinalKamboj please restate.

Comment: Turn on tracing on system.net to get more diagnostics.

Comment: Simply put remove infinite loop and put a print statement, then let's see whether it works, mostly it will print Callback and then `send called` or make a call with some network delay,which can be delayed for sometime and you would see `send called` is printed

Comment: @MrinalKamboj What you are saying is true, read the question again, I have added to it. 
what I am asking is that send called should be printed irrespective of what the callback does since callback should be in different thread right?

Comment: Why would be call back on a different thread, it is same thread continuation, that's why you are having an issue, this is how Async-Await also works, though there you can indicate to use any available context

Comment: @user2984602 [That is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847851/on-windows-c-does-socket-beginreceive-take-a-background-thread-before-or-af); the socket begin/end methods make use of the IOCP thread pool.

Comment: Documentation from msdn : When your application calls BeginSend, the system will use a separate thread to execute the specified callback method, and will block on EndSend until the Socket sends the number of bytes requested or throws an exception. If you want the original thread to block after you call the BeginSend method, use the WaitHandle.WaitOne method. Call the Set method on a T:System.Threading.ManualResetEvent in the callback method when you want the original thread to continue executing.

Comment: I don't know what IOCP thread pool is, sorry novice here, did I misinterpret the documentation.
@Amy Are you agreeing with MrinalKamboj Statement that it would execute on same thread.

Comment: @user2984602 Do you know what a thread pool is?  IOCP is a collection of threads windows keeps around to process I/O very efficiently.  I linked to an answer from my last comment that explains it in greater detail.  In short, yes, the callback is invoked on a separate thread.

Comment: IOCP is IO completion ports, that's a standard mechanism in windows to dispatch a network call, it doesn't use the process thread that you are assuming it is more of Hardware based threading. In fact for loop back it might not even use IOCP, as it is local and would be very quick. Try adding an explicit delay on server accepting the connect, this would make your program work as expected

Comment: In short don't mix the software threading with network call / IPC communication

Comment: It is not obvious what Send() method you are calling.  Not the one you  posted, it has 2 parameters.  So you probably inherited a non-asynchronous Send()